# Как узнать какой файл сервис не может найти?

Tags: windows, winapi

Внесла определённые изменения в системный сервис. При попытке его запуска выводится ошибка: `The {serviceName} service terminated with the following error: The system cannot find the file specified.` Как определить какой файл он не может найти? Может ли это быть из-за того, что неправильно настроила доступ к папке, в которой хранятся .dll, используемые этим сервисом?

Comment: Как-то упустил фразу "изменения в системный сервис"... С ключевыми словами "изменения" и "системный". А что Вы, собственно, изменили и где? Если пропатчили .exe или .dll, то понадобится обновить контрольную пропатченного сумму файла, прописанную в заголовке. Насколько я помню, при файле с неверной контрольной суммой симптом будет именно такой, как Вы указали

Comment: @SergeyNudnov вполне может быть. Как обновить контрольную сумму файла в заголовке?

Comment: Вот несколько линков, надеюсь, что помогут, но сам я эти программы не проверял: [1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19326/An-Analysis-of-the-Windows-PE-Checksum-Algorithm), [2](http://bytepointer.com/tools/index.htm#peupdate), [3](https://www.the-sz.com/products/checksum/)

Comment: @SergeyNudnov спасибо за ссылки. Просмотрев их, я поняла что дело не в этом. Почему я сделала такой вывод? Эти инструменты перезаписывают сами PE-файлы. А я делаю своё ПО по готовому алгоритму (переписала софт на другой ЯП). Всё те же WinAPI функции с теми ж параметрами использовались в той же последовательности. Код, с которого переписывала, рабочий. Сама проверяла. Там нет таких действий, но при этом всё работает как часы.

Comment: Все изменения косательно файлов:
изменила в реестре (`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\{serviceName}\Parameter\ServiceDll`) путь к dll, который естественно создала вместе с вспомогательным .ini-файлом (находятся в одной директории, имя .ini-файла как и в оригинальном коде).

Comment: Тогда все же Ваш самый надежный путь - это Process Monitor. Он должен показать в логе доступ к DLL. Попробуйте сначала с его помощью исследовать запуск рабочего сервиса - до его изменения

Comment: @SergeyNudnov проблема решилась, так и не выяснив в чём она заключалась. В оригинальном коде, помимо прописывания пути к новой .dll в реестре посредством запросов к системным библиотекам (которые работают с реестрами), иногда запись выполняется ещё и через запрос в cmd (`reg.exe add ...`), что я решила упустить, ведь у меня не было сомнений, что .NET не сможет сам изменить значение в реестре. Я это сочла за костыль.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov С одной стороны я ошибалась. Хоть .NET всё-таки изменял значение в реестре, сервис всё-равно почему-то не запускался по нелогичной для этой ситуации ошибке (ведь файл в старой записи тоже существовал). Проблема решилась созданием нового процесса `reg.exe` с передачей параметров для перезаписи значения в реестре, как и в коде. В чём разница между записью значения программным путём и через процесс `reg.exe` я так не поняла, ведь в обоих случаях состояние реестра было идентичным.

Answer (score 0):

[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) Вам в помощь. Запускаете, вводите в фильтр имя .exe подопытного сервиса, пытаетесь запустить, анализируете вывод монитора на предмет открываемых файлов. Массу интересного можно узнать!

Comment: На servicedefaults.com нашла информацию, что для запуска изменённого мною сервиса используется Command Line `%SystemRoot%\System32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService`. Попыталась запустить сервис через cmd с правами администратора коммандой `net start {serviceName}`. Отфильтровала события процессов по параметру, чтобы Command Line заканчивался на 'svchost.exe -k NetworkService' и нашла нужные мне события процесса svchost.exe. После моего запроса в cmd, svchost создал поток с TID = 1 (условно), который начал собирать в реестре нужные данные для запуска сервиса (пути .dll).

Comment: Потом services.exe создаёт поток с определённым TID. Поток с этим TID сразу же закрывается. После чего сразу же закрывается поток svchost.exe c TID, который собирал данные по нужному мне сервису. Результаты выполнения всех операций SUCCESS. Как только нашла цепочку нужных мне событий - сразу же поотключала все фильтры, чтобы ничего не упустить. Детально разобрала каждое событие, которое затрагивает запуск нужного мне сервиса. Даже информации о том, что событие не запустилось из-за того, что не нашло нужный ему файл, не нашла. Что очень странно для столь тонкого инструмента мониторинга.

Comment: Мой вывод: данный инструмент не помог мне, хотя я старалась максимально вникнуть в его работу.

Comment: Можно вообще попробовать отключить фильтр. А в момент получения ошибки запуска сервиса - отключить логирование. Событий будет гораздо больше, но Ваше там точно будет.